# $P(\varphi(n))\supset P(2^{\varphi(n)}-1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $\varphi: \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ be the Euler's Totient function and $P(m)$ be the set of all prime factors of $m$. I want to find a natural number $n$ such that
$$P(\varphi(n))\supset P(2^{\varphi(n)}-1)$$

Is my argument correct?

> Using Zsigmondy's theorem, for $n$ large enough, $2^{\varphi(n)}-1$ has a prime factor not dividing $2^k-1$ for all $k<\varphi(n)$.  Let $\varphi(n)=2^kt$ for some odd number $t$ so $t|(2^{\varphi(t)}-1)$. Since $\varphi(t)<\varphi(n)$, this implies there are an (odd) prime factor of $2^{\varphi(n)}-1$ not dividing $\varphi(n)$. Thus we can try with some small $n$ to get the conclusion.

Comment: It's quite unclear: are you trying to find such a natural number $n$, or are you trying to prove that no such number exists?